# Error 'can't assign to function call ' run on Command Line via Python

Tags: python, windows, command-line, subprocess, python-3.4

I'm trying to run a one line code on command line via Python.

For example this one is working;

```
py -c "import time;a=lambda x: [x for x in range(10)];print(a(5));time.sleep(2);print(a(15))"
```

I got the expected output with no error etc.

But when I try to open for example `Notepad.exe` via `subprocess`;

```
py -c "import subprocess;lul='Notepad.exe';subprocess.call([lul])"
```

It raises error

> SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

What's the problem here that I can't see? Also I tried to write `Notepad.exe` directly into `subprocess` instead of making a variable, same error.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Are you sure the error is coming from this code? Show the full traceback.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. What is `py`? The cpython binary is usually called `python` or `python3`.

Comment: @phihag I can't run Python on Command Line using `python` or etc. Only `py` works, don't know why.

Comment: `py` is the Windows Python launcher, described in [PEP 397](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/). I'm not sure it has anything to do with this issue though.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem via `py -3.4 ...`. The error implies the statement you're actually running attempts to assign a value to `subprocess.call([lul])`.